# Can not start Docker container

Tags: docker

I created ubuntu image using `docker-compose`. Here is the relevant code from `docker-compose.yml`:

```
ubuntu-os:
  container_name: ubuntu
  image: ubuntu
  volumes:
    - ubuntu-datavolume:/home/username/docker/.os/ubuntu/
volumes:
  ubuntu-datavolume:
```

It gets stopped as soon as it is started. I can not interract with the container. Here is relevant `docker ps -a`:

```
03dae5416b67    ubuntu    "/bin/bash"    12 minutes ago    Exited (0) 3 minutes ago    ubuntu
```

I have tried every possible combo of `docker start -a ubuntu` but with no luck. I want this image to persist data across restart so I created the volume. Any suggestions?

Creating a new container is not what I am looking for but to start the existing container. I don't want to run the container but start and interact.

Comment: How is this related to Java language? Pls, remove unnecessary tags from a question.

Comment: @itwasntme java has active members which know Docker. People usually don't watch tags like Docker on SO. I would be happy to remove the tag if my question is answered.

Comment: What do you see with docker logs 03dae5416b67?

Comment: @Chris It gives me nothing. No logs :/

Comment: Ah ok, I haven't got my laptop handy but I think there may possibly be something dodgy with the volumes entry in ubuntu-os, I don't think you need to specify the location within your docker directory, and maybe docker doesn't like it if you do. I can have a look later at a similar docker compose I have for Kafka where I have no problem persisting data.

Comment: Actually I'll go look now.....

Comment: @Chris Yeah, even I don't have any problems in persisting data in apps that has thread to keep it alive. No problem with db, amqp, etc. The problem is related to only ubuntu os. I really want to persist data between shutdown with ubuntu.

Comment: The location /home/username etc is in the container, does that exist? The persisted local location is handled internally by docker, you are just mapping to the container location. Is that your understanding, as I wouldn't expect to see /docker in the path

Comment: @Chris Yes, it exists.

Comment: Okay, if that's the case I can't see the problem, but can you share the Dockerfile for that ubuntu image?

Comment: @Chris I have created it using `docker-compose.yml`. I am not using `Dockerfile` yet. Once I solve the persistence issue, I will create the necessary `Dockerfile`.

Comment: But this is what I mean - the volumes is referencing /home/username/docker/.os/ubuntu/ - a location within the container, but if you are just using a standard ubuntu image does this location exist? Else you would need a Dockerfile to create your own image from ubuntu with that directory added

Comment: What happens if you map the volume to a directory that is definitely in the Ubuntu image, say /tmp - that would show if I am leading you in the wrong direction

Comment: @Chris I get it now. I cross checked the documentation but I am unable to find anything related to it. Can you write a code for me to handle that? I would like to persist it on host machine physical location: `/home/username/docker/.os/ubuntu/`.

Comment: I'm not sure if you get a choice over where it lives on the host, as docker manages that - I'll have a quick look in the docs at https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a ubuntu image which have an entry point `/bin/sh`. If you launch this without interactive/terminal linked, it will just run and exit with code 0. Your container finish successfully.

You can add the option:

```
  stdin_open: true
  tty: true
```

Referenced https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir

or add command line that do something. like:  `command: sleep 600000`